# Comment blocks between divs for positioning

Tags: html, css

I've recently come across a website and found that between most `div`s a comment block is being used to 'push' the elements down. In my mind this is not the correct way to do it, but is it acceptable to do it commercially?

**HTML**

```
<div class="layout__item">

    </div><!--

    --><div class="layout__item">

    </div><!--

    --><div class="layout__item">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.layout__item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 22px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: They are pushed down because of width:100%, and not because of the comment block. Also bare in mind that the wordpress editor automatically wraps everything inside <p></p> tags, taht means that if you go on a new line, it closes the previous <p> and opens a new one, resulting in new line

Comment: Yes this is a wordpress site

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14776780/1654265

Comment: I wonder this is just for asking why! Because you have width:100%, so the items are in rows, which exactly acts like `block`, however you'll have to deal with the white spaces, what is the point.

Comment: I asked why because I'm actively learning about HTML & CSS and was unaware of why this had been done. I have an answer now which has made everything much clearer of why the developer had done this.

Comment: That makes sense then. But don't do that in real cases :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments aren't there to "push the elements down", but to keep whitespace out of the rendered output while keeping the html readable. The key there is the `display: inline-block` in the css—without the comments between each of the `layout_item`s, the whitespace separating each of the tags in the source would find its way into the rendered output, which is usually not what you want in that situation.

There's a more in-depth discussion of this issue at https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/